# How to convert value of json from string to object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm using angular 8 and I have a json like this:

```
     validations: [
    {
      name: "required",
      validator: "Validators.required",
      message: "required"
    }
```

I dont know How I convert "Validators.required" (string)  to Validators.required?

Comment: That's not JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is you that have `var Validators = {required: true}` as `global` variable and you want to access it from the string from `validations` array.

You can access `global` `var Validators` with `window.Validators` or `window["Validators"]`.

To access `Validators.required` you can use `window.Validators.required` or `window["Validators"]["required"]`.

For that you can split `"Validators.required"` with `.` and use [`reduce`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_reduce.asp) to return `window["Validators"]["required"]` value as per below code.

```js
var Validators = {
  required: true
};

let validations = [{
  name: "required",
  validator: "Validators.required",
  message: "required"
}];

let result = validations[0].validator
              .split('.')
              .reduce((a, i) => a[i], window); // <- Use window to access global variable.
              
console.log(result);
```

---

Or if you are having `var Validators = {required: true}` inside any `component` then you can use `object` of that `component` with second parameter of `reduce`.

For example you have `component` object which has `Validators = {required: true}` then use code like below.

```js
let component = {
  Validators: {
    required: true
  }
};

let validations = [{
  name: "required",
  validator: "Validators.required",
  message: "required"
}];

let result = validations[0].validator
  .split('.')
  .reduce((a, i) => a[i], component);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use js function JSON.parse()

While parsing check for a valid json.
By using **JSON.parse()** in a try catch block

```
try { JSON.parse(json); return true; } catch (e) { return false; }}

var object = JSON.parse('validJSON')
```

Comment: This produces an error since the given content is not a valid JSON.

Comment: You can't use `'` with multi-line string literals. JSON strings have double quotes around the keys. And if this is indeed what OP is looking for, then it should be closed as a duplicate.